# Quickfix duplicate code with different fix versions

Tags: java, code-duplication, quickfix

I'm writing some code which deals with lots of different fix versions (4.2,4.3,4.4).
The issue I have is that when writing handler objects I am being forced to duplicate code because each fix version will use a different handler.
e.g.

```
@Handler    
public void executionHandler(quickfix.fix42.ExecutionReport execution, SessionID sessionID)  {
    System.out.println(execution.getClOrdID().getValue());
}

@Handler    
public void executionHandler(quickfix.fix43.ExecutionReport execution, SessionID sessionID)  {
    System.out.println(execution.getClOrdID().getValue());
}
```

The actual code I am writing is far more complex (I am retrieving several fields and manipulating the data). I can't think of how to reduce this duplication without resorting to reflection.

Comment: Are the fields the same and just the only thing that differs is the package (i.e. `fix42`, `fix43`)?

Comment: Are there many fields that your manipulating? If not, you can catch the different version like you show above, but then pass just the fields to a central, private method to do your calculations.

Comment: Yeh there are lots of fields...tbh I think the design of quickfix is pretty poor.

Comment: Reflection is your friend. Why fight it?

Comment: Speed...this application is latency sensitive.

Comment: One idea is create a method which does the common part and only write the extra processing in the handler functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, some of the features that make QuickFIX/J easier and safer to use also can create difficulties in situations like the one you describe. The handler methods and generated message classes are designed to support type safety but you actually want less type safety and more dynamic field access. The generated classes are sublclasses of `quickfix.Message` which is a subclass of `quickfix.FieldMap`. The FieldMap class has public accessors for getting field data. The typesafe message wrappers use these to get the message data.

For example,

`double averagePrice = message.getDouble(AvgPx.FIELD);`

This will work for any Message that contains the field. All the generated fields have a FIELD static member with the tag number. The `quickfix.MsgType` class also has constants for message types which can be useful for custom dynamic dispatching of messages.

If you are accessing message header fields like MsgType, remember to access those fields via the `message.getHeader()` method.

Here's a bonus tip. If you don't need or want the type safe message wrappers you can define a simple custom `quickfix.MessageFactory` that will just create basic `quickfix.Message` objects. This will result in a small performance improvement when processing incoming messages.